# MagSafe Charger not working

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power, magsafe

My MagSafe adapter stopped working 10 days ago, so I bought a replacement wire and replaced the original with this third-party wire. It worked fine until this morning.
It magically stopped charging!
So, I used one of those testers for current **(This might've been a mistake)** to check whether the charger was actually sending current or not.

*On touching the tester to the L-Shaped head, it sparked and then there was no current!*

I didn't connect it back to the MacBook since I'm afraid it might burn the socket or something which would ultimately cost me to change the entire Motherboard I believe as they are fitted into the PCB. (I'm not very educated on this stuff)

**Should I try connecting it back to the MacBook?** 
**Should I buy the original adapter from Apple?**

**This is what I mean by L-Shaped(60W):**

[image: L-Shaped connector]

**This is the tester I'm talking about:**

[image: Tester Image]

Comment: Could you please explain your MagSafe L-Adapter?

Comment: @Jackson1442 hmmm... It's 60W version. What else information do I need?

Comment: What *is* the L-Adapter?

Comment: Oh sry, Let me edit the question.

Comment: Ok, so did you actually replace only the *wire*, which is attached to the power brick? Or did you just buy a whole new power supply?

Comment: @Jackson1442 only wire, the part that attaches to the laptop not the easily replaceable power cable that goes into the wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tester you show is not for testing the output from the magsafe - my first concern is that with the size of its blade it is all too easy to connect two of the small terminals together - and from your description of "it sparked" then that may be what has happened.

I would not connect that power supply again to the mac, but I would replace it with a new one.

Or, if you have a friend with a known good power supply test your mac with that and if all is fine then buy a new one.

Comment: I've bought a third party adapter (Entire thing), the Apple one was kinda expensive.

Comment: Oh yes, I bought an Apple one the other month! Hope all is fine for you now. And don't use that tester on your laptop any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting your SMC? Are you positive the power cord is working? Try different plugs, different laptops, different power cords. Test this thoroughly as you don’t want to go through the rest of this answer just to find out it was a bad cord/outlet. If nothing in the above works, keep reading.

Based on your symptoms, and assuming the second power adapter is functional, it sounds too me like a bad MagSafe DC-In board. This is the board that collects the power from the MagSafe cable and transfers it to the battery. I’d suggest 1) running Apple Hardware Test with the adapter plugged in to test this. If the power test comes back faulty, and you’re reasonably sure that the cable is working, the MagSafe board is your most likely problem. If you feel comfortable with DIY repairs on your laptop, check out [this iFixit page](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-Unibody-13-Inch-and-15-Inch-MagSafe-DC-In-Board/IF163-011-1) where you can find the replacement part for ~$25 USD. If you don’t feel comfortable with this repair, take your computer in to an Apple Authorized Service Provider to get a quote for the repair. Good luck!

Please don’t hesitate to add comments/edits if you think this answer is wrong, incomplete or needs clarification.

Comment: The answer is helpful for someone who has a problem IN the Mac. But luckily it was just the adapter that was broken, my Mac is all fine. I've upvoted your answer as it can help someone else better. (It may not be visible due to my reputation)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise fully replacing your *entire* power supply with an apple original (look on craigslist or ebay for something less expensive), as this was a DIY-install, replacing only the cord on the power supply.

As many things could have gone wrong with the replacement, maybe a wire popped loose or something, I would advise not plugging this into your computer either.